# SQL left join with duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables structure:

[image]

I am just unable to get the required output as above using the left join:

```
SELECT K.[ID], 
       K.[KeyName], 
       K.Notes, 
       KR.isSignedIn
  FROM [dbo].[Keys] K
  LEFT JOIN 
           [dbo].[KeyRecords] KR WITH(NOLOCK) 
  ON
     K.ID = KR.Key_ID
  WHERE
        (KR.isSignedIn = 1 OR KR.isSignedIn is null)
```

I know the reason, it is because the KeyRecords table can have multiple entries for the same key. But how to make it check the last entry for that key only?

So I want all records from the Key table which have the last record isSignedIn = 1 in the records table. If no record of the key in the KeyRecords table I still want to show it.

Comment: you must be getting all 3 records, that's because `isSignedIn` is 1 for `KeyId = 1`as well. If you want to neglect that, something distinct should be there OR explicitly exclude it in `where`

Answer (score 0):

It's not the nicest solution, but this is what does the trick.
I have no idea how big your tables are or if you have any indexes on them.

```
select 
  k.ID, k.KeyName, K.Notes, KR.isSignedIn
from dbo.[Key] K
left join dbo.[KeyRecords] KR
  on kr.Key_ID = k.ID
where (
       select MAX(ID)
       from dbo.[KeyRecords] sub
       where sub.Key_ID = kr.Key_ID
      ) = 
      (
       select ID 
       from dbo.[KeyRecords] sub
       where sub.Key_ID = kr.Key_ID
       and sub.isSignedIn = 1
      )
or kr.ID is null
```

Please check the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8028/12).

Answer (score 0):

When you need "last entry for a key" use `CROSS or OUTER APPLY`:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM
    dbo.[Key] AS K
    OUTER APPLY
    (
      SELECT TOP(1) KeyRecords.isSignedIn
      FROM KeyRecords
      WHERE KeyRecords.Key_ID = K.ID
      ORDER BY KeyRecords.ID DESC
    ) AS A
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE isSignedIn = 1 OR isSignedIn IS NULL
ORDER BY ID
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c778/1/0).

What `CTE` does: for each `Key` find the row in the `KeyRecord` with the largest `ID`. (if such row doesn't exist, return `NULL`, so we need `OUTER APPLY` here).

Then filter results further and remove those that have `isSignedIn = 0`.

This variant would work efficiently if you have small tables or index on `KeyRecords`: `(Key_ID, ID)`. Most likely you already have primary key on `ID`, so simple index on `Key_ID` with `isSignedIn` as included column should be enough.

[image: Execution plan]

You can see from the plan that for each row in the `Key` table the server does one index seek on the `KeyRecords` table. If `Key` table is small and `KeyRecords` is large it is very efficient overall.